# What's the number of possible structures of alkanes $C_n H_{2n+2}$?

Tags: graph-theory

When my chemistry teacher started listing out all possible structure of the hydrocarbon $C_7H_{16}$, my mind flied to look for a general formula. Let me mathematicalize this problem.

> Here, we have $n$ points on a plane, all connected with some lines, following these rules:
>
> 1. no points can have more than $4$ lines attached;
> 2. number of lines between any $2$ points is $1$;
> 3. no loop formed.
>
> We only concern how the points are linked by lines, their positions on the plane doesn't matter. So what is the number of possible structure when there's $n$ points?

E.g., when there's $5$ points, all possibilities are: (I use $C$ to denote points)[image]

When there's 6,

[image]

I started by finding an algorithm to list out all possibilities, I found this too hard and turned to find a way to check if 2 structure are actually the same, which I also failed later. I suspect this has something to do with recursive things. Please help, Thanks.

p.s. I'm not sure if I've made the rules clearly, please point out any problem you see.

Comment: Aw! No [Benzene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzene)?

Comment: What about optical isomers?

Comment: @ Richard & Awesome: NOOOOO

Comment: I still remember the day our teacher gave us for pentadecane and went for a walk outside.

Comment: I think it's useless for larger hydrocarbons as many of them will be too much sterically hindered to exist.

Comment: Let's discuss their existence mathematically.

Comment: NOOOOO­­­­­­­­­

Comment: The sequence [OEIS A000602](https://oeis.org/A000602) counts the number of such hydrocarbons. I'm not sure if this helps answer your question, because it wasn't clear to me what your question is.

Comment: @Richard, alkanes are trees.

Comment: http://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/cayley.html

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Benzene is an hydrocarbon. The question was edited from hydrocarbon to alkane.

Comment: @Richard, OK...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tree.html) is a start for what you are looking for. The number of different carbon chains is the same as the number of non isomorphic trees.

Comment: there is an additional constraint though, no vertex can have more than 4 edges attached to it. so certain trees are forbidden

Comment: Good point. This is why I am a mathematician and not a chemist! lol