# Deriving the general formula of alkane using graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

With context as per this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754784/whats-the-number-of-possible-structures-of-alkanes-c-n-h-2n2), it turns out that if $n$ represents the number of skeleton's in any one of the graphs which OP has drawn, then the total hydrogen required to fulfil [valency of carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_(chemistry)) (I.e: give each carbon node 4 attachments) is $2n+2$. How do we prove this?

It is often a formula given in chemistry classes as a fact to memorize, I hope that using mathematics there can be an understanding on why the relation between number of hydrogen and carbon must be such

Ideally looking for a non induction based proof.

Comment: Hmm why the downvote?

Comment: Think of a chain of carbon atoms with a hydrogen atom on each end. Besides the ends, there ate 2 hydrogens on each carbon, so ...

Comment: There are other cases than the carbons being at ends, the straight chain alkane is only one particular graph @Peter

Comment: True, so decompose the tree into chains, noting that there are no Hs at the breaks. Alternatively use induction, showing that making an alkane by adding 1C to any alkane following the rule produces another alkane following the rule.

Comment: Hmm I was looking for a non induction proof,  I didn't understand your first point about the decomposing thing. Could you rephrase the statement?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think induction is the only way to formally prove it. As for the decomposition, you can break up the molecule into straight chains. Each chain would have 2n-2 Hs, so the total is the sum of all those, less 2 Hs for each join. Or, for each C after the first there is one join reducing the Hs by 2, so total is 4n less 2(n-1). This is not a formal proof though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not going to be any way to avoid using induction some way or another.  Induction is pretty much the only way you can ever prove statements about finite structures of arbitrary size.  (Ultimately, this is because "finiteness" is *defined* in terms of induction, with the natural numbers defined as the smallest inductive set.)

Here is probably the simplest way to prove it.  Every time you attach a new carbon to your alkane, you replace a hydrogen (that used to be in the spot where you attached your new carbon) with a $\mathrm{CH_3}$, giving a net increase of $2$ hydrogens.  So every new carbon you add increases the number of hydrogens by $2$.  Building this up inductively from the base case of $\mathrm{CH_4}$, this means there will always be $2n+2$ hydrogens.  (Here I am glossing over one important detail: how do you know you can build up every alkane by repeatedly replacing hydrogens with $\mathrm{CH_3}$?  How to prove this depends on exactly what your definitions are, but it crucially uses the fact that the carbons must form a tree, without any cycles.)

Or, here's a more high-tech way of thinking about it using a little machinery of graph theory.  Consider the carbons as a tree.  By a basic theorem in graph theory, a tree with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges (this is proved by induction, so you still aren't avoiding induction here).  So, there are $n-1$ bonds between the carbons.  Each carbon must have $4$ bonds, giving a total of $4n$ bonds where you count each bond twice (once for each end).  Of these $4n$ bonds, $2(n-1)$ of them are accounted for by carbon-carbon bonds.  Thus there must be $4n-2(n-1)=2n+2$ carbon-hydrogen bonds, and thus $2n+2$ hydrogens.